# Is $f(x, y) = x - y$ injective and surjective?

Tags: functions

Consider $f(x,y) = x-y$ for $ℤ × ℤ^+ → ℤ$. Is this injective and surjective?

I think it's not injective because there are infinitely many values of $x$ and $y$ which can have the same difference, such as (50, 10), (49, 9) and so on.

But I think it's surjective because every integer in the codomain is mapped to at least once.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: You're right, it is fine for me.

Comment: You found counter-examples to show that $f$ is not injective and your instincts are correct about surjectivity. Can you come up with a proof for surjectivity?

Comment: I had a basic thought about this: Let $r = x - y$.  Since $x$ and $y$ are both integers, $r$ is also an integer, hence it exists in the codomain and is mapped to.
I am not sure if this is exhaustive enough.

Comment: @user794805 Better to just say $r=(r+1)-1 = f(r+1,1)$. But yes, this is very straightforward.

Comment: For negative $n$, $f(0,|n|)=-|n|=n$. Combine that with Morgan's proof for $n\ge 0$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You suggested the following proof of surjectivity:

> Let $r = x - y$. Since $x$ and $y$ are both integers, $r$ is also an integer, hence it exists in the codomain and is mapped to.

This actually isn't a proof of surjectivity. If I give you an $r$, like $6$, you need to find $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y > 0$ such that $x-y = r$ (in this case, $7$ and $1$ would do).

Comment: Thanks! But how would I make that a general proof? Would it be sufficient to choose a specific $r$ and show that it's true? Wouldn't I have to show that it's true for all possible values of $r$?

Comment: You need to show it for all possible values of $r$; but you can do that by doing it for an arbitrary fixed $r$. I chose $6$ for the sake of argument, but if you can do it when you don't know anything about $r$, then you've got a proof.